# PKIX path building - NIFI is throwin an error when calling API via InvokeHTTP processor

Tags: java, linux, web-services, apache-nifi

I am getting the below error in NIFI when I call an API which is hosted in another server. (source and destination are Linux servers)

I need to add the server certificates in my current server to resolve this issue.

Can anyone provide the step by step commands that I need to execute to resolve this issue?

[image: Nifi ERROR]

Nifi Log:

```
2021-05-11 16:56:40,619 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP InvokeHTTP[id=0176115c-90fb-164a-a491-7eb6554327bc] Routing to Failure due to exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:327)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:265)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:646)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:361)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:451)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:428)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:184)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1198)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1107)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:400)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:372)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP.onTrigger(InvokeHTTP.java:850)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1174)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:128)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:630)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
        ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: the instruction to create truststore & add certificates into it is the same for all java applications. which truststore to use in invokehttp could be set through `SSL Context Service` parameter.

Comment: @daggett - In NiFI we do not write any coding. It is a intergation tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The InvokeHTTP in NiFi is a client of your API. This means that the InvokeHTTP needs to be able to trust your remote server to ensure it's not connecting to a malicious service. To do this, we need to add the Certificate Authority/Root Authority of the remote service to InvokeHTTP's truststore. The CA required will be shown in the 'Issuer' fields of the service's server certificate.

To get the CA, you can follow this blog: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2018/11/07/get-the-ca-cert-for-curl/, and retrieve the CA into a pem file with:

```
echo quit | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect server:443 > cacert.pem
```

Then, you can use Keystore Explorer (https://keystore-explorer.org) to create a new truststore file (which is a much easier way to manage key/truststores), and import the certificate cacert.pem into this truststore.

You then configure an **SSL Context Service** in the InvokeHTTP processor, which references the truststore you created.

Comment: Keystore explorer worked well for me.  Thanks for recommending it!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow the below steps. and restarted the NIFI Instance. It started  working.

```
1. echo -n | openssl s_client -connect <server name>:<port> |sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/examplecert.crt

2. keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore /apps/java/jdk1.8.0_211-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts  -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias mito -file /tmp/examplecert.crt
```

Comment: Usual port: 443